# Ночной режим для сайта HTML

Tags: html, css

Я написал скрипт который позволяет ставить ночной режим для сайта,
то есть нажимая на картинку я просто меняю файл со стилями и все классно работает,
но когда я например включаю ночной режим и перезагружаю страницу то включается по умолчанию
светлый режим. Можно ли как то сделать так, что бы браузер понимал что если я включил ночной режим, то
после перезагрузки его не нужно сбрасывать? И если я перехожу например на другую страницу на моем сайте,
то ночной режим тоже выключается. Заранее спасибо за любые подсказки!

```
Скрипт ↓
let moon = document.getElementById("moonA");
moon.onclick = function () {
    let theme = document.getElementById("glownystyle");
    let photo = document.getElementById("moon");
    if (photo.getAttribute("src") == "sun.svg") {
        theme.href = "glStyle.css";
        photo.src = "moon.svg";
    } else {
        theme.href = "glStyle2.css";
        photo.src = "sun.svg";
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно к примеру записать ключ/значение в localStorage. Ключ 'theme', значение 'dark' и 'light' в зависимости от выбора. При перезагрузке страницы считываете последний установленный параметр и выставляете что надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, нужно отменить дефолтную функцию после клика. Возможно, эти посты помогут. Успехов!

https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method

Comment: Ответ-ссылка - не формат для StackOverflow, так как ссылка может сломаться в будущем и ваш ответ станет бесполезен для других посетителей. Старайтесь всю ключевую информацию писать прямо в ответе. Ссылки можно давать как дополнительные источники информации.

Answer (score 2):

запоминайте текущее состояние режима (например, в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)), и восстанавливайте его при перезагрузке страницы

```js
/**
 * предопределяем компоненты режимов
 */
const modes = {
    day : {
        css : 'glStyle2.css',
        svg : 'sun.svg'
    },
    night : {
        css : 'glStyle.css',
        svg : 'moon.svg'
    }
}

/**
 * задаем идентификатор ячейки хранилища текущего режима 
 * в localStorage ("skin")
 */
const storageId = 'skin'

/**
 * определяем элементы страницы (кнопку переключение режима,
 * ссылку на таблицу стилей и ссылку на изображение в svg)
 */
const moon = document.getElementById('moonA')

const stylesheet = document.getElementById('glownystyle')

const svg = document.getElementById('moon')

/**
 * получаем из localStorage компоненты сохраненного режима с фолбеком:
 * если ранее данные режима еще не сохранялись в localStorage, и
 * ячейка хранилища соответсвенно окажется пуста, используем компоненты
 * по умолчанию из преопределенного ранее объекта (modes.day)
 */
let activeMode = localStorage.getItem(storageId) || modes.day

/**
 * применяем полученные компоненты к элементам страницы
 */
stylesheet.src = activeMode.css
svg.src = activeMode.svg

/**
 * устанавливаем на кнопку переключение режима 
 * обработчик события click
 */
moon.onclick = function () {
    /**
     * после клика определяем текущий режим -
     * сравниваем содержимое объекта activeMode,
     * определенного после загрузки страницы, с
     * объектом компонентов по умолчанию modes.day,
     * и если эти объекты идентичны, присваиваем
     * activeMode компоненты альтернавного режима
     * modes.night, и наоборот
     */
    if (activeMode.css === modes.day.css) {
        activeMode = modes.night
    } else {
        activeMode = modes.day
    }

    /**
     * запоминаем текущий режим в localStorage на
     * случай перезагрузки страницы 
     */
    localStorage.setItem(storageId, activeMode)

    /**
     * применяем компоненты выбранного режима
     * к элементам страницы
     */
    stylesheet.src = activeMode.css
    svg.src = activeMode.svg
}
```